# How can I get webpack to output raw css files but with everything resolved?

Tags: webpack

I have an AngularJS (v1.5) project that uses a library called [angular-css](https://github.com/castillo-io/angular-css) to load css dynamically.  It helps by loading/unloading styles as needed and makes css naming collisions much less likely.  The entire project was already configured with it and it is only now being set up for Webpack.

What I want is to somehow configure webpack to resolve any url's and such in each css/scss file and place it into the build as a stylesheet with its original name, such that it still gets picked up by angular-css as intended.  I tried to accomplish this with file loader, which doesn't seem to work if chained with css-loader (for resolution), and with the ExtractTextPlugin which seems to want to dump everything into one file which won't work either.

Here is the relevant part of the webpack.config.js (the commented out portion was my original attempt with file-loader)  :

[image]

and here is a look at how its set up in a component, for clarity.

[image]

Comment: For clarity, this works correctly if I use only file-loader (or file-loader chained after sass-loader if it's an scss file), UNLESS something in the stylesheet needs resolution.  Then it breaks because css-loader outputs a format that angular-css cannot use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put [`extract-loader`](https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader) between the `sass-loader` and `file-loader` to evaluate on the fly. This should resolve everything before `file-loader` puts it in a file.

Comment: Oh wow, this worked easy peasy.  I really wish I had asked sooner lol.

Comment: Unfortunately extract-loader is broken for about two years now. And propably abandoned. I still have no new solution.